# Exhausted Resultset SQL Exception occur in if condition else condition

Tags: java

I written following code but it throws a "Resultset exhausted" error.

```
String dt = rs.getTimestamp("GuaranteeDate")+"";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Date date = dateFormat1.parse(dt);
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);

Integer attributeID = 0;
String query1 ="select distinct M_attributesetinstance_id from M_storage where m_Product_id="+M_Product_ID;
attributeID = DB.getSQLValue(trxName, query1);

Timestamp MaufacuringDate = null;
String query = "select manufacturingdate from m_attributesetinstance where m_attributesetinstance_id="+attributeID;

try
{
    pstmt = null;
    rs = null;

    pstmt = DB.prepareStatement(query.toString(),null);
    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next())
    {
        MaufacuringDate = rs.getTimestamp("manufacturingdate");
    }
}  
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (MaufacuringDate!= null) 
{
    DateTime ManufacturingDate = new DateTime(MaufacuringDate);

    try
    {
        if((!"".equalsIgnoreCase(dt) || dt!=null) && percentage>=0  &&  GuaranteeDate != null) 
        {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date d1 = c1.getTime();
            DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime(d1);

            try 
            {
                // c1.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));
                // ReadableInstant date2;
                Days d = Days.daysBetween(ManufacturingDate, dateTime);
                int days = d.getDays();

                float calulateddays = (float)(days*(percentage/100.0f));
                Integer roundeddays = Math.round(calulateddays);
                c1.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));
                c1.add(Calendar.DATE, -roundeddays);  // number of days to add

                try
                {
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(sdf.format(c1.getTime()));
                    MinGuaranteeDate = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MinGuaranteeDate = null;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
            catch (ParseException e) 
            {
                MinGuaranteeDate = null;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        MinGuaranteeDate = null;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("MinGuaranteeDate :"+MinGuaranteeDate);
    System.out.println("TodayDate :"+GuaranteeDate);

    if(MinGuaranteeDate==null || MinGuaranteeDate.after(GuaranteeDate)) 
    {
        continue;
    }
}
else
{
    Timestamp GRNDate = null;

    String query2 = "select distinct Movementdate from M_inout m "
                               +"inner join m_inoutline mil ON (m.M_Inout_ID = mil.M_Inout_id) where mil.M_Product_Id="+M_Product_ID;

    try
    {
        pstmt = null;
        rs = null;

        pstmt = DB.prepareStatement(query2.toString(),null);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next())
        {
                                GRNDate = rs.getTimestamp("Movementdate");
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                       // String dt1 = rs.getTimestamp("GuaranteeDate")+"";
                        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        Date date1 = dateFormat1.parse(dt);
                        DateTime dateTime2 = new DateTime(date1);

                         DateTime GRDate = new DateTime(GRNDate);

                         try{
                                if((!"".equalsIgnoreCase(dt) || dt!=null) && percentage>=0  &&  GuaranteeDate!=null) {
                                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                                    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                                    Date d1 = c1.getTime();
                                    //DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime(d1);

                                    try {
                                         // c1.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));
                                         //ReadableInstant date2;
                                        Days d = Days.daysBetween(GRDate, dateTime);
                                        int days = d.getDays();


                                        float calulateddays = (float)(days*(percentage/100.0f));
                                        Integer roundeddays = Math.round(calulateddays);
                                        c1.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));
                                        c1.add(Calendar.DATE, -roundeddays);  // number of days to add

                                        try{
                                            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                                            Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(sdf.format(c1.getTime()));
                                            MinGuaranteeDate = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
                                        }catch(Exception e){
                                            MinGuaranteeDate = null;
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                                        MinGuaranteeDate = null;
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }   

                                }
                                else {
                                    continue;
                                }


                                }catch(Exception e) {
                                    MinGuaranteeDate = null;
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }


                                    System.out.println("MinGuaranteeDate :"+MinGuaranteeDate);
                                    System.out.println("TodayDate :"+GuaranteeDate);

                                    if(MinGuaranteeDate==null || MinGuaranteeDate.before(GuaranteeDate)) {
                                        continue;
                                    }

                      }
                      }
if (rs.getBigDecimal(11).signum() == 0) {
                list.add(new MStorage(ctx, rs, trxName));

                }

            }
        }   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        s_log.log(Level.SEVERE, sql, e);
    } finally {
        DB.close(rs, pstmt);
        rs = null;
        pstmt = null;
    }
```

in above code gives the error on statement of bigdecimal

```
 if (rs.getBigDecimal(11).signum() == 0) {
                    list.add(new MStorage(ctx, rs, trxName));



                }
```

on this line
Kindly help me out

Comment: Show the statcktrace please.

Comment: }
  }
      
  PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;
  try {
   pstmt = DB.prepareStatement(sql, trxName);
   pstmt.setInt(1, M_Locator_ID > 0 ? M_Locator_ID : M_Warehouse_ID);
   pstmt.setInt(2, M_Product_ID);
   if (!allAttributeInstances) {
    pstmt.setInt(3, M_AttributeSetInstance_ID);
   } else if (GuaranteeDate != null) {
    pstmt.setTimestamp(3, GuaranteeDate);
   }

   rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

   Timestamp MinGuaranteeDate= null;
   Integer percentage = 0;
   while (rs.next()) {

Comment: its not in proper format

Comment: that is not the stacktrace

Comment: All code execute properly with correct values but give the error on bigdecimal

Comment: and it goes in catch block

Comment: and what is the Output of `e.printStackTrace();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out whether MStorage calls rs.next() again, as you already used up all the results within another block:

```
                 while (rs.next())
             {
                 MaufacuringDate = rs.getTimestamp("manufacturingdate");
             }
```

Comment: how can i find that one

Comment: if not then what can i do

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have iterated over the record using `Resultset` object `rs` and now your **rs cursor** is at the end of the record/ or we can say **it not pointing to any record**.

Still your code below is using rs object which is **exhausted** and not pointing to any record/table row.

> `if (rs.getBigDecimal(11).signum() == 0) {
>                           list.add(new MStorage(ctx, rs, trxName));
>                       }`

**Possible solution :**: Create a new statement, execute query and get the new `ResultSet` object whose cursor will be at the start of record (Note: Cursor at -1 (use `.next()`)) and iterate over the record ad get the required result.

**OR** use some logic inside previous iteration over record and get the result there itself instead of iterating again .